# How to use Julia map on a Dict of Dicts?

Tags: dictionary, julia

I want to iterate over a collection of dicts and evaluate a function that takes one Dict at a time. In R-speak I have a list of lists and want to lapply my function - which takes a list as input - for each sublist:

```
function dfun(d::Dict)
   println(collect(keys(d)))
   println(collect(values(d)))
   end

# my dict of dicts
d = [1 => ["a" => 1.1], 2 => ["b" => 3.12]]
[2=>["b"=>3.12],1=>["a"=>1.1]]

# works?
julia> dfun(d[1])
ASCIIString["a"]
[1.1]

# maps?
map(dfun,d)
ERROR: no method dfun((Int64,Dict{ASCIIString,Float64}))
 in map at abstractarray.jl:1183
```

What's the correct way of doing this? I'm surprised it sends (Int64,Dict{ASCIIString,Float64}) to the funciton and not just Dict{ASCIIString,Float64}

(sorry for crossposting  - but i think SO is just so much nicer to search...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Julia, iteration over a dictionary is iteration over key/value pairs, not iteration over values (or iteration over keys, as in Python):

```
julia> for x in d println(x); println(typeof(x)) end
(2,["b"=>3.12])
(Int64,Dict{ASCIIString,Float64})
(1,["a"=>1.1])
(Int64,Dict{ASCIIString,Float64})
```

so that's why your map is getting `(Int64,Dict{ASCIIString,Float64})`-typed args.  If you want the values, you could ask for those specifically:

```
julia> map(dfun, values(d))
ASCIIString["b"]
[3.12]
ASCIIString["a"]
[1.1]
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
```

but if you're not returning anything from the function, it feels a little weird to use `map` because you're building an unneeded Array of nothing.  I'd just do

```
julia> for v=values(d) dfun(v) end
ASCIIString["b"]
[3.12]
ASCIIString["a"]
[1.1]
```

Comment: ha, now that's a good point. the only reason i use `map` is because i wanted to make it consistent with `pmap` (which I call on the same function if I am on a cluster). but I guess I could just use `@parallel for`? I read this: **Julia’s pmap is designed for the case where each function call does a large amount of work.** which is my case - hence `pmap`. any thoughts?

Comment: `map` vs not-`map` (same with `pmap`) is about whether it makes sense to build an array of the return values.  If yes (even if the return value is relatively boring, like an array of success booleans you expect is mostly going to be True), then use `map`.  If not, then you might as well avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

got an answer on the mailing list:

```
map(dfun,values(d))
```